# get font name and size from bigquery tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset that has some tables and data in different fonts.
Is there a way to get font name using SQL or python from these tables?
Here is an example of the font formats stored in BQ table

| string_id | string |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | ℕ |
| 3 | Men |
| 4 |  |

I'd like to find a way to distingue rows by font name.
Expected results

| font_ID | agg_string_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 |
| 2 | 3,5 |
| 3 | 4 |

Comment: a database has no font formats, the gui might, so what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Just distinguishing rows by different fonts would work too. I edited the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option - you can use info about Unicode Characters Blocks (you can find simplified version at the bottom of answer)

So, using such a luxury table (`char_blocks`) you can use below

```
select a.*, font_name
from your_table a
join char_blocks b
on unicode(string) between block_start and block_end
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

or if you want aggregate by font

```
select font_name, string_agg('' || string_id) agg_string_id
from your_table a
join char_blocks b
on unicode(string) between block_start and block_end
group by font_name
```

with output

[image]

And finally, below is that luxury table I used in above queries

```
create temp table char_blocks  as (
  select 'Basic Latin' font_name, 0 block_start, 127 block_end union all
  select 'Latin-1 Supplement', 128, 255 union all
  select 'Latin Extended-A', 256, 383 union all
  select 'Latin Extended-B', 384, 591 union all
  select 'IPA Extensions', 592, 687 union all
  select 'Spacing Modifier Letters', 688, 767 union all
  select 'Combining Diacritical Marks', 768, 879 union all
  select 'Greek and Coptic', 880, 1023 union all
  select 'Cyrillic', 1024, 1279 union all
  select 'Cyrillic Supplement', 1280, 1327 union all
  select 'Armenian', 1328, 1423 union all
  select 'Hebrew', 1424, 1535 union all
  select 'Arabic', 1536, 1791 union all
  select 'Syriac', 1792, 1871 union all
  select 'Arabic Supplement', 1872, 1919 union all
  select 'Thaana', 1920, 1983 union all
  select 'NKo', 1984, 2047 union all
  select 'Samaritan', 2048, 2111 union all
  select 'Mandaic', 2112, 2143 union all
  select 'Syriac Supplement', 2144, 2159 union all
  select 'Arabic Extended-A', 2208, 2303 union all
  select 'Devanagari', 2304, 2431 union all
  select 'Bengali', 2432, 2559 union all
  select 'Gurmukhi', 2560, 2687 union all
  select 'Gujarati', 2688, 2815 union all
  select 'Oriya', 2816, 2943 union all
  select 'Tamil', 2944, 3071 union all
  select 'Telugu', 3072, 3199 union all
  select 'Kannada', 3200, 3327 union all
  select 'Malayalam', 3328, 3455 union all
  select 'Sinhala', 3456, 3583 union all
  select 'Thai', 3584, 3711 union all
  select 'Lao', 3712, 3839 union all
  select 'Tibetan', 3840, 4095 union all
  select 'Myanmar', 4096, 4255 union all
  select 'Georgian', 4256, 4351 union all
  select 'Hangul Jamo', 4352, 4607 union all
  select 'Ethiopic', 4608, 4991 union all
  select 'Ethiopic Supplement', 4992, 5023 union all
  select 'Cherokee', 5024, 5119 union all
  select 'Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics', 5120, 5759 union all
  select 'Ogham', 5760, 5791 union all
  select 'Runic', 5792, 5887 union all
  select 'Tagalog', 5888, 5919 union all
  select 'Hanunoo', 5920, 5951 union all
  select 'Buhid', 5952, 5983 union all
  select 'Tagbanwa', 5984, 6015 union all
  select 'Khmer', 6016, 6143 union all
  select 'Mongolian', 6144, 6319 union all
  select 'Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics Extended', 6320, 6399 union all
  select 'Limbu', 6400, 6479 union all
  select 'Tai Le', 6480, 6527 union all
  select 'New Tai Lue', 6528, 6623 union all
  select 'Khmer Symbols', 6624, 6655 union all
  select 'Buginese', 6656, 6687 union all
  select 'Tai Tham', 6688, 6831 union all
  select 'Combining Diacritical Marks Extended', 6832, 6911 union all
  select 'Balinese', 6912, 7039 union all
  select 'Sundanese', 7040, 7103 union all
  select 'Batak', 7104, 7167 union all
  select 'Lepcha', 7168, 7247 union all
  select 'Ol Chiki', 7248, 7295 union all
  select 'Cyrillic Extended C', 7296, 7311 union all
  select 'Georgian Extended', 7312, 7359 union all
  select 'Sundanese Supplement', 7360, 7375 union all
  select 'Vedic Extensions', 7376, 7423 union all
  select 'Phonetic Extensions', 7424, 7551 union all
  select 'Phonetic Extensions Supplement', 7552, 7615 union all
  select 'Combining Diacritical Marks Supplement', 7616, 7679 union all
  select 'Latin Extended Additional', 7680, 7935 union all
  select 'Greek Extended', 7936, 8191 union all
  select 'General Punctuation', 8192, 8303 union all
  select 'Superscripts and Subscripts', 8304, 8351 union all
  select 'Currency Symbols', 8352, 8399 union all
  select 'Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols', 8400, 8447 union all
  select 'Letterlike Symbols', 8448, 8527 union all
  select 'Number Forms', 8528, 8591 union all
  select 'Arrows', 8592, 8703 union all
  select 'Mathematical Operators', 8704, 8959 union all
  select 'Miscellaneous Technical', 8960, 9215 union all
  select 'Control Pictures', 9216, 9279 union all
  select 'Optical Character Recognition', 9280, 9311 union all
  select 'Enclosed Alphanumerics', 9312, 9471 union all
  select 'Box Drawing', 9472, 9599 union all
  select 'Block Elements', 9600, 9631 union all
  select 'Geometric Shapes', 9632, 9727 union all
  select 'Miscellaneous Symbols', 9728, 9983 union all
  select 'Dingbats', 9984, 10175 union all
  select 'Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A', 10176, 10223 union all
  select 'Supplemental Arrows-A', 10224, 10239 union all
  select 'Braille Patterns', 10240, 10495 union all
  select 'Supplemental Arrows-B', 10496, 10623 union all
  select 'Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B', 10624, 10751 union all
  select 'Supplemental Mathematical Operators', 10752, 11007 union all
  select 'Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows', 11008, 11263 union all
  select 'Glagolitic', 11264, 11359 union all
  select 'Latin Extended-C', 11360, 11391 union all
  select 'Coptic', 11392, 11519 union all
  select 'Georgian Supplement', 11520, 11567 union all
  select 'Tifinagh', 11568, 11647 union all
  select 'Ethiopic Extended', 11648, 11743 union all
  select 'Cyrillic Extended-A', 11744, 11775 union all
  select 'Supplemental Punctuation', 11776, 11903 union all
  select 'CJK Radicals Supplement', 11904, 12031 union all
  select 'Kangxi Radicals', 12032, 12255 union all
  select 'Ideographic Description Characters', 12272, 12287 union all
  select 'CJK Symbols and Punctuation', 12288, 12351 union all
  select 'Hiragana', 12352, 12447 union all
  select 'Katakana', 12448, 12543 union all
  select 'Bopomofo', 12544, 12591 union all
  select 'Hangul Compatibility Jamo', 12592, 12687 union all
  select 'Kanbun', 12688, 12703 union all
  select 'Bopomofo Extended', 12704, 12735 union all
  select 'CJK Strokes', 12736, 12783 union all
  select 'Katakana Phonetic Extensions', 12784, 12799 union all
  select 'Enclosed CJK Letters and Months', 12800, 13055 union all
  select 'CJK Compatibility', 13056, 13311 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A', 13312, 19903 union all
  select 'Yijing Hexagram Symbols', 19904, 19967 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs', 19968, 40959 union all
  select 'Yi Syllables', 40960, 42127 union all
  select 'Yi Radicals', 42128, 42191 union all
  select 'Lisu', 42192, 42239 union all
  select 'Vai', 42240, 42559 union all
  select 'Cyrillic Extended-B', 42560, 42655 union all
  select 'Bamum', 42656, 42751 union all
  select 'Modifier Tone Letters', 42752, 42783 union all
  select 'Latin Extended-D', 42784, 43007 union all
  select 'Syloti Nagri', 43008, 43055 union all
  select 'Common Indic Number Forms', 43056, 43071 union all
  select 'Phags-pa', 43072, 43135 union all
  select 'Saurashtra', 43136, 43231 union all
  select 'Devanagari Extended', 43232, 43263 union all
  select 'Kayah Li', 43264, 43311 union all
  select 'Rejang', 43312, 43359 union all
  select 'Hangul Jamo Extended-A', 43360, 43391 union all
  select 'Javanese', 43392, 43487 union all
  select 'Myanmar Extended-B', 43488, 43519 union all
  select 'Cham', 43520, 43615 union all
  select 'Myanmar Extended-A', 43616, 43647 union all
  select 'Tai Viet', 43648, 43743 union all
  select 'Meetei Mayek Extensions', 43744, 43775 union all
  select 'Ethiopic Extended-A', 43776, 43823 union all
  select 'Latin Extended-E', 43824, 43887 union all
  select 'Cherokee Supplement', 43888, 43967 union all
  select 'Meetei Mayek', 43968, 44031 union all
  select 'Hangul Syllables', 44032, 55215 union all
  select 'Hangul Jamo Extended-B', 55216, 55295 union all
  select 'High Surrogates', 55296, 56191 union all
  select 'High Private Use Surrogates', 56192, 56319 union all
  select 'Low Surrogates', 56320, 57343 union all
  select 'Private Use Area', 57344, 63743 union all
  select 'CJK Compatibility Ideographs', 63744, 64255 union all
  select 'Alphabetic Presentation Forms', 64256, 64335 union all
  select 'Arabic Presentation Forms-A', 64336, 65023 union all
  select 'Variation Selectors', 65024, 65039 union all
  select 'Vertical Forms', 65040, 65055 union all
  select 'Combining Half Marks', 65056, 65071 union all
  select 'CJK Compatibility Forms', 65072, 65103 union all
  select 'Small Form Variants', 65104, 65135 union all
  select 'Arabic Presentation Forms-B', 65136, 65279 union all
  select 'Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms', 65280, 65519 union all
  select 'Specials', 65520, 65535 union all
  select 'Linear B Syllabary', 65536, 65648 union all
  select 'Linear B Ideograms', 65664, 65776 union all
  select 'Aegean Numbers', 65792, 65840 union all
  select 'Ancient Greek Numbers', 65856, 65920 union all
  select 'Ancient Symbols', 65936, 65984 union all
  select 'Phaistos Disc', 66000, 66032 union all
  select 'Lycian', 66176, 66192 union all
  select 'Carian', 66208, 66256 union all
  select 'Coptic Epact Numbers', 66272, 66288 union all
  select 'Old Italic', 66304, 66336 union all
  select 'Gothic', 66352, 66368 union all
  select 'Old Permic', 66384, 66416 union all
  select 'Ugaritic', 66432, 66448 union all
  select 'Old Persian', 66464, 66512 union all
  select 'Deseret', 66560, 66624 union all
  select 'Shavian', 66640, 66672 union all
  select 'Osmanya', 66688, 66720 union all
  select 'Osage', 66736, 66800 union all
  select 'Elbasan', 66816, 66848 union all
  select 'Caucasian Albanian', 66864, 66912 union all
  select 'Linear A', 67072, 67440 union all
  select 'Cypriot Syllabary', 67584, 67632 union all
  select 'Imperial Aramaic', 67648, 67664 union all
  select 'Palmyrene', 67680, 67696 union all
  select 'Nabataean', 67712, 67744 union all
  select 'Hatran', 67808, 67824 union all
  select 'Phoenician', 67840, 67856 union all
  select 'Lydian', 67872, 67888 union all
  select 'Meroitic Hieroglyphs', 67968, 67984 union all
  select 'Meroitic Cursive', 68000, 68080 union all
  select 'Kharoshthi', 68096, 68176 union all
  select 'Old South Arabian', 68192, 68208 union all
  select 'Old North Arabian', 68224, 68240 union all
  select 'Manichaean', 68288, 68336 union all
  select 'Avestan', 68352, 68400 union all
  select 'Inscriptional Parthian', 68416, 68432 union all
  select 'Inscriptional Pahlavi', 68448, 68464 union all
  select 'Psalter Pahlavi', 68480, 68512 union all
  select 'Old Turkic', 68608, 68672 union all
  select 'Old Hungarian', 68736, 68848 union all
  select 'Hanifi Rohingya', 68864, 68912 union all
  select 'Rumi Numeral Symbols', 69216, 69232 union all
  select 'Yezidi', 69248, 69296 union all
  select 'Old Sogdian', 69376, 69408 union all
  select 'Sogdian', 69424, 69472 union all
  select 'Chorasmian', 69552, 69584 union all
  select 'Elymaic', 69600, 69616 union all
  select 'Brahmi', 69632, 69744 union all
  select 'Kaithi', 69760, 69824 union all
  select 'Sora Sompeng', 69840, 69872 union all
  select 'Chakma', 69888, 69952 union all
  select 'Mahajani', 69968, 70000 union all
  select 'Sharada', 70016, 70096 union all
  select 'Sinhala Archaic Numbers', 70112, 70128 union all
  select 'Khojki', 70144, 70208 union all
  select 'Multani', 70272, 70304 union all
  select 'Khudawadi', 70320, 70384 union all
  select 'Grantha', 70400, 70512 union all
  select 'Newa', 70656, 70768 union all
  select 'Tirhuta', 70784, 70864 union all
  select 'Siddham', 71040, 71152 union all
  select 'Modi', 71168, 71248 union all
  select 'Mongolian Supplement', 71264, 71280 union all
  select 'Takri', 71296, 71360 union all
  select 'Ahom', 71424, 71472 union all
  select 'Dogra', 71680, 71744 union all
  select 'Warang Citi', 71840, 71920 union all
  select 'Dives Akuru', 71936, 72016 union all
  select 'Nandinagari', 72096, 72176 union all
  select 'Zanabazar Square', 72192, 72256 union all
  select 'Soyombo', 72272, 72352 union all
  select 'Pau Cin Hau', 72384, 72432 union all
  select 'Bhaiksuki', 72704, 72800 union all
  select 'Marchen', 72816, 72880 union all
  select 'Masaram Gondi', 72960, 73040 union all
  select 'Gunjala Gondi', 73056, 73120 union all
  select 'Makasar', 73440, 73456 union all
  select 'Lisu Supplement', 73648, 73648 union all
  select 'Tamil Supplement', 73664, 73712 union all
  select 'Cuneiform', 73728, 74736 union all
  select 'Cuneiform Numbers and Punctuation', 74752, 74864 union all
  select 'Early Dynastic Cuneiform', 74880, 75072 union all
  select 'Egyptian Hieroglyphs', 77824, 78880 union all
  select 'Egyptian Hieroglyph Format Controls', 78896, 78896 union all
  select 'Anatolian Hieroglyphs', 82944, 83568 union all
  select 'Bamum Supplement', 92160, 92720 union all
  select 'Mro', 92736, 92768 union all
  select 'Bassa Vah', 92880, 92912 union all
  select 'Pahawh Hmong', 92928, 93056 union all
  select 'Medefaidrin', 93760, 93840 union all
  select 'Miao', 93952, 94096 union all
  select 'Ideographic Symbols and Punctuation', 94176, 94192 union all
  select 'Tangut', 94208, 100336 union all
  select 'Tangut Components', 100352, 101104 union all
  select 'Khitan Small Script', 101120, 101616 union all
  select 'Tangut Supplement', 101632, 101760 union all
  select 'Kana Supplement', 110592, 110832 union all
  select 'Kana Extended-A', 110848, 110880 union all
  select 'Small Kana Extension', 110896, 110944 union all
  select 'Nushu', 110960, 111344 union all
  select 'Duployan', 113664, 113808 union all
  select 'Shorthand Format Controls', 113824, 113824 union all
  select 'Byzantine Musical Symbols', 118784, 119024 union all
  select 'Musical Symbols', 119040, 119280 union all
  select 'Ancient Greek Musical Notation', 119296, 119360 union all
  select 'Mayan Numerals', 119520, 119536 union all
  select 'Tai Xuan Jing Symbols', 119552, 119632 union all
  select 'Counting Rod Numerals', 119648, 119664 union all
  select 'Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols', 119808, 120816 union all
  select 'Sutton SignWriting', 120832, 121504 union all
  select 'Glagolitic Supplement', 122880, 122912 union all
  select 'Nyiakeng Puachue Hmong', 123136, 123200 union all
  select 'Wancho', 123584, 123632 union all
  select 'Mende Kikakui', 124928, 125136 union all
  select 'Adlam', 125184, 125264 union all
  select 'Indic Siyaq Numbers', 126064, 126128 union all
  select 'Ottoman Siyaq Numbers', 126208, 126272 union all
  select 'Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols', 126464, 126704 union all
  select 'Mahjong Tiles', 126976, 127008 union all
  select 'Domino Tiles', 127024, 127120 union all
  select 'Playing Cards', 127136, 127216 union all
  select 'Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement', 127232, 127472 union all
  select 'Enclosed Ideographic Supplement', 127488, 127728 union all
  select 'Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs', 127744, 128496 union all
  select 'Emoticons (Emoji)', 128512, 128576 union all
  select 'Ornamental Dingbats', 128592, 128624 union all
  select 'Transport and Map Symbols', 128640, 128752 union all
  select 'Alchemical Symbols', 128768, 128880 union all
  select 'Geometric Shapes Extended', 128896, 129008 union all
  select 'Supplemental Arrows-C', 129024, 129264 union all
  select 'Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs', 129280, 129520 union all
  select 'Chess Symbols', 129536, 129632 union all
  select 'Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A', 129648, 129776 union all
  select 'Symbols for Legacy Computing', 129792, 130032 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B', 131072, 173776 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C', 173824, 177968 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D', 177984, 178192 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E', 178208, 183968 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F', 183984, 191456 union all
  select 'CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement', 194560, 195088 union all
  select 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension G', 196608, 201536 union all
  select 'Tags', 917504, 917616 union all
  select 'Variation Selectors Supplement', 917760, 917984 union all
  select 'Supplementary Private Use Area-A', 983040, 1048560 union all
  select 'Supplementary Private Use Area-B', 1048576, 1114111 
);
```